# Using module include in OCaml

Tags: module, types, expression, ocaml

In OCaml 3.11, I want to "extend" an existing module using the include directive, like so:

```
module MyString = struct
  include String
  let trim s = ...
end
```

No problem.  But now I want to expose this module's type explicitly (i.e. in a .mli file).  I want something like this:

```
module MyString : sig
  include String
  val trim : string -> string
end
```

But the include syntax is not correct because String refers to a module, not a module type (and the compiler does indeed barf).  How can I refer to the module type for String here (without having write it out explicitly in a sig expression)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

OCaml 3.12 will have a construct like `module type of M` that I believe would have solved your problem. Meanwhile, you can have the compiler generate the lengthy signature with `ocamlc -i`. Sorry, but I think it's the best you can do with 3.11.